# is UNC S.M.A.R.T. Error serious? need to take action?

Tags: linux, smart, drive-failure

I have a 300G Western Digital Raptor, recently showing UNC SMART, wondering anyone who has experience knows should I replace it and get warranty form WD?

Details of smartctl -a as follows:

```
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE-p6 amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital VelociRaptor
Device Model:     WDC WD3000HLFS-01G6U0
Serial Number:    WD-WXD0C79C8807
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 0ac3cfaf0
Firmware Version: 04.04V01
User Capacity:    300,069,052,416 bytes [300 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  Exact ATA specification draft version not indicated
Local Time is:    Thu Apr 19 16:03:33 2012 CST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x84) Offline data collection activity
                    was suspended by an interrupting command from host.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 4800) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  59) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x303f) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   195   195   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       49036
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   199   196   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       3008
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       425
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   086   086   000    Old_age   Always       -       10292
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       404
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       268
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       426
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   117   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       30
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       4
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 749 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 749 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6972 hours (290 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 44 cb 53 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0053cb44 = 5491524

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 40 10 a6 4e 58 01 08      00:16:23.812  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 10 9e 32 5b 00 08      00:16:17.646  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 10 9e 32 5b 00 08      00:16:17.645  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 00 08      00:16:17.645  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]
  60 08 10 9e 32 5b 00 08      00:16:11.412  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 748 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6972 hours (290 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 44 cb 53 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0053cb44 = 5491524

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 10 9e 32 5b 00 08      00:16:11.412  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 10 9e 32 5b 00 08      00:16:11.412  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 00 08      00:16:11.412  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]
  60 00 30 1e cb 53 06 08      00:16:05.199  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 30 1e cb 53 06 08      00:16:05.180  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 747 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6972 hours (290 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 44 cb 53 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0053cb44 = 5491524

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 30 1e cb 53 06 08      00:16:05.199  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 30 1e cb 53 06 08      00:16:05.180  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 30 1e cb 53 06 08      00:16:05.178  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 30 1e cb 53 06 08      00:16:05.178  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 30 1e cb 53 06 08      00:16:05.178  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 746 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6972 hours (290 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 44 cb 53 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0053cb44 = 5491524

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 30 1e cb 53 06 08      00:15:58.945  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 30 1e cb 53 06 08      00:15:58.945  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 30 1e cb 53 06 08      00:15:58.945  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 30 1e cb 53 06 08      00:15:58.945  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 30 1e cb 53 06 08      00:15:58.944  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 745 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6972 hours (290 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 44 cb 53 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0053cb44 = 5491524

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 30 1e cb 53 06 08      00:15:52.727  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 30 1e cb 53 06 08      00:15:52.727  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 30 1e cb 53 06 08      00:15:52.727  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 30 1e cb 53 06 08      00:15:52.727  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 30 1e cb 53 06 08      00:15:52.726  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]


SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: ok soz, done now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do the replace if you can.

On the other hand these are 'only' read errors which is not that bad. If you write to that sector then you can be only sure if it has defects.

I would run the vendors utility to check (they also run smart tests) if it has problems. They usually make bootable cds available.

You can and should run a self test which you can do from linux by issuing

```
smartctl -t long /dev/your-device
```

wait a couple of hours (it will show an estimate). Then check again with

```
smartctl -a /dev/your-device
```

If it says `Completed without errors` you are fine. If not go for the vendors utility to check the drive.

Answer (score 7):

Read errors can be caused by something as simple as losing power during a write operation. Alone, they don't suggest any hardware issues with the drive.